# Hovering on the video doesn't play the video. Clicking on the video opens a new tab

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, preact

**Current behavior**
Hovering on a video tile doesn't play the video as expected
Clicking on the video opens a new tab (Expected to open the video player on the same screen)

**Desired behavior**
Hovering on a video should play the video
Clicking on the video should open up the video player and video should play

**Test code to reproduce**
Hovering on a video should play the video

```
const urls = [`https://cat-press.com/cat-movies/firework`]
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    it(`Should load the videos and autoplay one: ${url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      // Scroll to feed
      cy.get('.cy-grid').scrollIntoView()
      // Should hover over to the video at index 1
      cy.get(`.cy-thumbnail-link`).eq(1).trigger('mouseover')
     
    })
  })
```

Clicking on the video opens a new tab (Expected to open the video player on the same screen)

```
const urls = [`https://cat-press.com/cat-movies/firework`]
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    it(`Should load the videos and autoplay one: ${url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      // Scroll to feed
      cy.get('.cy-grid').scrollIntoView()
      // Should hover over to the video at index 1
      cy.get(`.cy-thumbnail-link`).eq(1).trigger('click')
     
    })
  })
```

[image]

updated the reproducible example in

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-tiny/tree/opens-new-tab

Comment: Whats the HTML (or clickable widget details) of a `.cy-thumbnail-link` element?

Comment: If hover is not working, try cypress real events https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events

Comment: @A J I tried realEvents as well. it didn't work.

Comment: @traktor Attached the email of widget details

Comment: @user2237529, I also tried to do the same and fix your code but I was also unable to fix it by implementing the workaround people have posted for an alternative of hover(). But by adding the same code 4 time, it looks like video is playing. I know it's not a good pattern
cy.get('.cy-thumbnail-link').eq(1).trigger('mouseover')
cy.get('.cy-thumbnail-link').eq(1).trigger('mouseover')
cy.get('.cy-thumbnail-link').eq(1).trigger('mouseover')
cy.get('.cy-thumbnail-link').eq(1).trigger('mouseover')

Comment: @user2237529 the complete widget could have event handlers (added in JavaScript) that could modify or prevent the `<a>`  link performing its default action. Importantly the link element is not the expected target of user clicks. Suggest trying to fire the click on the `alt="Play"` image to see what difference it makes. Depending on how devious the script is, it could also rely on  `mouseover`, `mousedown` and/ or  `mouseup` events being fired before `click`.

Comment: @ArekKhatry Thanks for that workaround. it partially works. When the video at index (1) starts playing when hovered, video at index 0 should go back to it's initial state. But it's not. One of the business requirement is to ensure that previously played video is gone back to the starting point with play button displayed. When hover is called multiple times, play button is never displayed. The video just freezes at the last played moment. However, manually that's not the case

Comment: @traktor used `'.cy-thumbnail-link > div > img'` but it still opens a new tab upon click event. I also tried hovering prior to clicking and it still opens in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the hovering issue by adding an explicit wait:

```
// Click on first thumbnail
      cy.get(`.cy-thumbnail-link`)
        .eq(1)
        .trigger("mouseover")
        //.trigger("mouseenter")
      cy.wait(3000)
```